# Show that random walk is a random variable

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I am working on this question.

> Suppose $\{X_n, n \ge 1\}$ are random variable on the probability
>   space $(\Omega, \mathcal{B},P)$ and define the induced random walk by 
>   \begin{align*} S_0=0, \, S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i, \, n \ge 1 \end{align*}
>   Let  \begin{align*} \tau:=\inf \{n>0: S_n>0 \} \end{align*} be the 
>   first upgoing ladder time. Prove that $\tau$ is a random variable.
>   Assume we know $\tau(\omega) < \infty$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$.
>   Prove $S_{\tau}$ is a random variable.

What I tried. 
So, I know some thing is a random variable if it is measurable or 
\begin{align}
[X \le  \lambda] \in \mathcal{B} \text{ for all } \lambda \in \mathbb{R}
\end{align}
If we apply this to $\tau$ we get
\begin{align*}
&\{\tau \le \lambda\}=\{\inf \{n>0: S_n>0 \}  \le \lambda\}
\\&= \left\{\inf \{n>0: \sum_{i=1}^n X_i>0 \}  \le \lambda\right\}
\end{align*}
I am stuck now what should I do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** write
$$
S_\tau = \sum_{t=1}^\infty 1_{ \{ \tau = t \} } S_t
$$

**Hint 2:** the set $\{S_\tau\in B\}$ is also $$\bigcup_{t=1}^\infty \{\tau = t, S_t\in B\}$$

Comment: give one me one more hint. Thanks

Comment: @Boby then the set $\{S_\tau\in B\}$ is also $\bigcup \{\tau = t, S_t\in B\}$

Comment: And $\{\tau=t, S_t \in B\}$ is measurable because  it's a composition of two measurable sets???

Comment: *intersection*,  yes :)

Comment: Let me reiterate.  $\{S_\tau \in B\}=\bigcup\{\tau=t, S_t \in B\}$ is measurable because $\{\tau=t, S_t \in B\}$ is measurable since its a an intersection of sets of the type $\{S_1 \le 0\} \cap ... \cap \{S_t>0\}$, correct? Just want to make sure I understand.

Comment: @Boby this is it!

Answer (score 4):

Note that the event $$\{\tau = n \} = \{S_1\le0\}\cap ... \cap \{S_{n-1}\le0\}\cap\{ S_n>0\}$$

But now observe that $S_i $ is a random variable, so all the events $\{S_i \le 0\}$ and $\{S_n > 0\}$ are measurable.

Now you have $$\{ \tau \le n \} = \bigcup_{i=1}^n\{\tau = i\}$$ and each of $\{\tau = i\}$ is measurable.